# How to add 'edit','delete','revision' buttons at page level - Drupal 8?

Tags: drupal, module, nodes, drupal-8

I am working on a drupal 8 website and I would like to know how to enable 'View','Edit','Revision' buttons on a page level as below:

[image]

Can these buttons be added at 'node' level without editing module.node file? Can someone guide on this?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the `Primary admin actions` block in the region you want (/admin/structure/block) and manage the node permissions of your users roles.